# directx 11 change texture using PSSetShaderResources

Tags: c++, directx-11

Hi I am just learning directx11 and have come across a problem with PSSetShaderResources

if I change textures before the call to swapchain->Present only the first texture is displayed.
if I change textures between Present calls both are displayed but on consecutive frames.

Is there anyway of changing textures with PSSetShaderResources so I can use both (or more) on a single frame?

I know I can use texture arrays but it appears to me that you must have same size textures?

also I could upload two textures (or more) at a time but I would then have to have conditional statements within shader.

Below is the drawing loop I am using. And the simple shader that I am using

any help would be appreciated.

Paul

24OCT2014

---

```
tempBool = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)             //change 2 to texCount
    {

    devcon->UpdateSubresource(pConstantBuffer, 0, NULL, &cb, 0, 0);
    devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &pConstantBuffer);
    devcon->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &pConstantBuffer);

    tempBool = !tempBool;

    if (tempBool)
    {

        devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &pTex[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &pTex[1]);
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < texRun[j]; i++)
        {

            devcon->Draw(obLens[curPos+i], obStarts[curPos+i]);
        }

        curPos += texRun[j];
    }

    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
```

---

```
Texture2D txDiffuse : register( t0 );
SamplerState samLinear : register( s0 );

cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 )
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;

    float4 vLightDir;
    float4 vLightColor;
};

struct VOut
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 Norm : NORMAL;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD;

};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float3 Norm : NORMAL, float2 Tex : TEXCOORD)
{
    VOut output = (VOut)0;
    output.Pos = mul( position, World );
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, View );
    output.Pos = mul( output.Pos, Projection );
    output.Norm = mul(Norm, World);
    output.Tex = Tex;

    return output;
}


float4 PShader0(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float3 Norm : NORMAL,
         float2 Tex : TEXCOORD ) :     SV_TARGET
{

    float4 diffuse = 0;

    diffuse = txDiffuse.Sample( samLinear, Tex  );


    float4 finalColor = 0;

    finalColor = diffuse; // * 0.2;
    finalColor += saturate( dot((float3)vLightDir,Norm) * diffuse); 


    finalColor.a = 1.0;

    return finalColor;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to draw? Two objects with two different textures or one object with two textures on top of each other?

Comment: I am drawing a road and curb they are separate objects. the road is about 10 objects and at the moments the curb is 8. What I am trying to do is draw all road objects with one texture. then change the texture and draw all curb objects. hope this explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally tracked down the error it was in my object loading code and nothing to do width direct3d

I was Loading second lot of objects over the first lot

for first lot of objects I am reading into  verts  which is my vertex data pointer

for the second lot I was also reading into verts instead of &verts[firstVertsCount]

anyway thanks for the help

Paul